# How to use a specific media formatter with a specifc route in Web Api

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi project with controllers that return JSONP. For this I'm using a JsonPMediaTypeFormatter class - I now have to merge these controllers with a 2nd Web Api project which doesn't use custom formatters. How do deliver JSONP for particular routes ie

"api/ProductsController/{action}/{id}  - returns JSONP

"api/LookupController/{action}/{id} - no custom formatter

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);

        config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter());
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't specifically a per-route way of having formatters, but there is a `per-controller configuration` which you can use to have specific formatters. For example, in your scenario you could have a common base controller for certain set of controllers and decorate that base controller with the per-controller configuration attribute.

Web API Sample for creating a per-controller configuration:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ControllerSpecificConfigSample/ReadMe.txt

Comment: Link is no longer valid